# AspNet: Cookie value is not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, cookies

The value of a cookie is not changing. I'm using localhost. I'm debugging
using Visual Studio 2013.

I'm using the following pattern for properties:

```
public int ModeIdx
{
    get
    {  
        return Convert.ToInt32(Page.Request.Cookies["keksGS"].Values["modIdx"]);
    }
    set
    { 
        Page.Response.Cookies["keksGS"].Values["modIdx"] = value.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Even a simple `ModeIdx++` isn't working. `ModeIdx` keeps the old value. The `keksGS` cookie is initialized properly.

My initial thought was that the "Firefox 42.0" browser doesn't have enough time to update the cookie (`Page.Request` keeping the old value). Thus, I added `Page.Response.Flush();`. Nothing has changed.

My latest thought is that I am missing a basic thing. I can't figure what.

Can you please help me in this matter?

Thank You!

Comment: When you say `ModeIdx++` isn't working, are you calling that multiple times within a single page load? Since you're writing to `Response` and reading from `Request` - calling `++` more than once between page loads will only increment once. Also, is there a reason you're not using `Session` instead?

Comment: I'm calling `ModeIdx++` only in a button_Click event. Maybe cause I don't know about `Session`.

Comment: Are you using the value in the cookie client-side (for example, is javascript reading it?) Or is it purely for the server? If it is for the server, I'd recommend using `Session` instead, as it handles this all for you.

Comment: purely for the server

Comment: Then I would change the code to be `get { return (int)Session["modIdx"]; } set { Session["modIdx"] = value; }`. Should work perfectly fine, then (note you may have to add some logic to the getter that handles the situation where `modIdx` has never been set).

Comment: great! please write this as answer, it's working now. The logic for `modIdx` never set' situation was implemented in `Page_init` and  updated for `Session` . Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, glad it's working mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this value is only being used by the server, and ASP.NET is *already* adding cookies to track the session (assuming it wasn't explicitly disabled), you can simply leverage the `Session` functionality.

Change your implementation to the following:

```
public int ModeIdx
{
    get 
    {  
        var result = Session["modIdx"] as int?;
        return result ?? 0; //Default to 0 if we can't cast to int, or the value was never set.
    }
    set { Session["modIdx"] = value; }
}
```